# Avoid line wrap between ::before pseudo-element and next word

Tags: css, pseudo-element, word-wrap

### The problem

I use `::before` to generate a pseudo-element to display a small image left of the anchor text of links. However, when re-sizing the browser window's width, the line may become wrapped between the small image and the first word of the link anchor text, which is undesired.

### Desired result

I want to keep the small image and the first word of the link anchor text together on the same line.

I keep `display: inline` on the a-tag because the link anchor text shall be able to wrap line, not as a whole atomic box, but so that its first word(s) fill up the current line and any remaining words continue on the next line.

Also, the text *after* the link shall continue on the same line as the last word of the link anchor text (provided there is space for its first word of course).

Note 1) If I would use `display:inline-block` on the a-tag, the entire link anchor text would wrap as a whole, which I do not want.

Note 2) I use `display:inline-block` on the pseudo-element because I need to set its width and height.

Note 3) I have tried with setting `white-space: pre` on the pseudo-element, but that did not solve the problem.

Thanks!

### The code

The code is at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/widheg/otkfz4o4/) and repeated below for completeness.

My HTML:

```
<p>
Text text <a class="pre-icon" href="#">FirstWord word2 word3</a> text after link.
</p>
```

My CSS:

```
.pre-icon::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBgAKAJEAADM2Zv///////wAAACH5BAUUAAIALAAAAAAGAAoAAAINBIRimdvHFETOUWglKwA7);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: .13em;
    margin-right: .25em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkbg3nnh/) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the line break happens between the pseudo-element and the content, so you can't avoid it by setting `white-space` only to the pseudo-element.

Instead, you can wrap the content of the anchor inside a span, set `white-space: nowrap` to the entire anchor, and restore the initial `white-space: normal` in the span.

```css
.pre-icon {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.pre-icon > span {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```css
.pre-icon::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBgAKAJEAADM2Zv///////wAAACH5BAUUAAIALAAAAAAGAAoAAAINBIRimdvHFETOUWglKwA7);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: .13em;
  margin-right: .25em;
}
.pre-icon {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.pre-icon > span {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
Text text <a class="pre-icon" href="#"><span>FirstWord word2 word3</span></a> text after link.
```

Comment: Thanks, a short and neat solution!

Answer (score 2):

While it would be really cool if we could finally get a :first-word selector (Great post by Chris Coyier about that: https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/), you probably need an extra span to do this.  Here's a fork on your fiddle that looks to be doing what you described:

https://jsfiddle.net/0hrn2Lao/

HTML:

```
<p>Text text <a class="pre-icon" href="#">
  <span>FirstWord</span> word2 word3</a> text after link.
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.pre-icon span {
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:underline;}

.pre-icon span::before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:6px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:transparent;
  background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBgAKAJEAADM2Zv///////wAAACH5BAUUAAIALAAAAAAGAAoAAAINBIRimdvHFETOUWglKwA7);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin-left:.13em;
  margin-right:.25em;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Basically, put the pseudo element with the image on the span containing the first word, then let the span be `inline-block`, without having to put the `inline-block` rule on the `<a>` element itself.

If you wanted, you could probably use some jQuery to insert the span around the first word of `<a class="pre-icon">` throughout the document - but if you're specifically adding that class, maybe it's not a lot of effort to just drop the span in manually too...depends on your pain tolerance, I guess :-)